# jQuery change div

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two div's and I doing this div's change

```
div class="switchLeft

div class="switchRight" 

<tab> 
(function ($) {  

    $(".switchLeft").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("switchLeft switchRight"); 
    });

})(jQuery);
</tab>
```

and I have other two div's
I changed the div above, I would like to see that change this div

I have done this but not working:

```
$(".switchLeft").click(function (){
{ $(this).toggleClass("switchLeft switchRight"); });
var myClass = $(this).attr("class");

if (myClass == "switchLeft") {
    $('.advertTabMenu').hide();
    $('.searchTabMenu').show();
}
else {
    $('.searchTabMenu').hide();
    $('.advertTabMenu').show();
}

};
```

I can not add code to the site.

Comment: Could you try to clarify the question?  It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, you closed the function before the codeblock and hence your statements were never executed.

Your code:

```
$(".switchLeft").click(function (){
{ $(this).toggleClass("switchLeft switchRight"); });//Closed the function here
var myClass = $(this).attr("class");

if (myClass == "switchLeft") {
    $('.advertTabMenu').hide();
    $('.searchTabMenu').show();
}
else {
    $('.searchTabMenu').hide();
    $('.advertTabMenu').show();
}
};//Invalid syntax
```

Use the following.

```
          $(".switchLeft").click(function (){
            {
            $(this).toggleClass("switchLeft switchRight"); 
            var myClass = $(this).attr("class");

            if (myClass == "switchLeft") {
                $('.advertTabMenu').hide();
                $('.searchTabMenu').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.searchTabMenu').hide();
                $('.advertTabMenu').show();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Look at the second line of your code block "});", you closed the function there.

Comment: I have a question mr ashwin How do I add sites with the code?I use <tab> CODE </tab>, but not working

Comment: RIGHT? BUT NOT WORKING (function ($) {
   $(".switchLeft").click(function (){
            {
            $(this).toggleClass("switchLeft switchRight"); 
            var myClass = $(this).attr("class");

            if (myClass == "switchLeft") {
                $('.advertTabMenu').hide();
                $('.searchTabMenu').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.searchTabMenu').hide();
                $('.advertTabMenu').show();
            }

        });
})(jQuery);